# one to many And one to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

This is projects migrate

```
    Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('start_date');
        $table->string('end_date');
        $table->string('con');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this is timesheets migrate

```
    Schema::create('timesheets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('project_id');
        $table->string('day');
        $table->string('month');
        $table->string('year');
        $table->string('jalali');
        $table->string('timesheet_h');
        $table->string('timesheet_m');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and this users migrate

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->string('salary_base');
        $table->string('salary_base_h');
        $table->string('start_contract');
        $table->string('end_contract');
        $table->string('start_insurance');
        $table->string('end_insurance')->nullable();
        $table->string('first_salary');
        $table->string('date_birth');
        $table->string('melli_code');
        $table->string('s_number');
        $table->string('nda');
        $table->string('work_rules');
        $table->string('end_work')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This my project model

```
public function timesheets()
{
    return $this->hasMany(timesheet::class,'project_id');
}
```

This my timesheet model :

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(project::class,'project_id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

and This my User model

```
public function project_peoples()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\project_people');
}
public function timesheets()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(timesheet::class);
}

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(project::class);
}
```

Now I return my query from projects

```
public function allProject()
{
    $projects=project::with(['timesheets','users'])->get();

    return $projects;
  }
```

This is ok but user_id Users in timesheets.user_id And I can not get it out timesheets and get it

This controller return project and timesheet by project_id in timesheet but user_id in timesheet I do not know how to get this into the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [dot syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load nested relationships:

```
project::with('timesheets.users')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"id":1,"name":"\u067e\u0631\u0648\u0698\u0647 \u062a\u0627\u06cc\u0645 \u0634\u06cc\u062a","start_date":"1111\/11\/11","end_date":"1111\/11\/11","con":"\u062f\u0631\u062d\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u062c\u0631\u0627","created_at":"2018-01-02 10:54:11","updated_at":"2018-01-02 10:54:11","timesheets":[{"id":7,"user_id":"2","project_id":"1","day":"12","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/12","timesheet_h":"5","timesheet_m":"24","created_at":"2018-01-02 12:40:12","updated_at":"2018-01-02 13:47:09","users":{"id":2,"name":"\u0645\u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f \u0633\u0644\u06cc\u0645\u0627\u0646\u06cc","mobile":"0000","salary_base":"1000000","salary_base_h":"20000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1000\/00\/00","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"1212","s_number":"1212","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 12:36:07","updated_at":"2018-01-02 12:36:07"}},{"id":8,"user_id":"1","project_id":"1","day":"13","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/13","timesheet_h":"10","timesheet_m":"10","created_at":"2018-01-03 05:59:13","updated_at":"2018-01-03 05:59:13","users":{"id":1,"name":"\u0645\u062c\u06cc\u062f \u0641\u06cc\u0636\u06cc","mobile":"00","salary_base":"3000000","salary_base_h":"10000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1111\/11\/11","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"00","s_number":"00","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48","updated_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48"}},{"id":9,"user_id":"2","project_id":"1","day":"14","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/14","timesheet_h":"10","timesheet_m":"15","created_at":"2018-01-04 07:17:44","updated_at":"2018-01-04 07:17:44","users":{"id":2,"name":"\u0645\u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f \u0633\u0644\u06cc\u0645\u0627\u0646\u06cc","mobile":"0000","salary_base":"1000000","salary_base_h":"20000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1000\/00\/00","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"1212","s_number":"1212","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 12:36:07","updated_at":"2018-01-02 12:36:07"}},{"id":10,"user_id":"2","project_id":"1","day":"16","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/16","timesheet_h":"10","timesheet_m":"60","created_at":"2018-01-06 07:17:21","updated_at":"2018-01-06 07:17:21","users":{"id":2,"name":"\u0645\u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f \u0633\u0644\u06cc\u0645\u0627\u0646\u06cc","mobile":"0000","salary_base":"1000000","salary_base_h":"20000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1000\/00\/00","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"1212","s_number":"1212","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 12:36:07","updated_at":"2018-01-02 12:36:07"}}]},{"id":2,"name":"\u067e\u0631\u0648\u0698\u0647 \u062a\u0633\u062a\u06cc","start_date":"1111\/11\/11","end_date":"1111\/11\/11","con":"\u062f\u0631\u062d\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u062c\u0631\u0627","created_at":"2018-01-02 11:28:03","updated_at":"2018-01-02 11:28:03","timesheets":[{"id":3,"user_id":"1","project_id":"2","day":"12","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/11","timesheet_h":"8","timesheet_m":"12","created_at":"2018-01-02 11:39:46","updated_at":"2018-01-02 11:39:46","users":{"id":1,"name":"\u0645\u062c\u06cc\u062f \u0641\u06cc\u0636\u06cc","mobile":"00","salary_base":"3000000","salary_base_h":"10000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1111\/11\/11","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"00","s_number":"00","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48","updated_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48"}},{"id":4,"user_id":"1","project_id":"2","day":"12","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/10","timesheet_h":"4","timesheet_m":"11","created_at":"2018-01-02 11:40:41","updated_at":"2018-01-02 13:49:45","users":{"id":1,"name":"\u0645\u062c\u06cc\u062f \u0641\u06cc\u0636\u06cc","mobile":"00","salary_base":"3000000","salary_base_h":"10000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1111\/11\/11","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"00","s_number":"00","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48","updated_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48"}},{"id":6,"user_id":"1","project_id":"2","day":"12","month":"10","year":"1396","jalali":"1396\/10\/12","timesheet_h":"1","timesheet_m":"12","created_at":"2018-01-02 12:06:31","updated_at":"2018-01-02 13:49:37","users":{"id":1,"name":"\u0645\u062c\u06cc\u062f \u0641\u06cc\u0636\u06cc","mobile":"00","salary_base":"3000000","salary_base_h":"10000","start_contract":"1111\/11\/11","end_contract":"1111\/11\/11","start_insurance":"1111\/11\/11","end_insurance":null,"first_salary":"100000","date_birth":"1111\/11\/11","melli_code":"00","s_number":"00","nda":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","work_rules":"\u062f\u0627\u0631\u062f","end_work":null,"created_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48","updated_at":"2018-01-02 10:53:48"}}]}]
```

This is my return i have 2 users but repeat my 2 users :(